# How to Override the OK button in Reminder notification

Tags: windows-phone-7

I use ScheduledActionService to create a reminder with Uri.  I like to know:
1) It is possible override the ok button or to write some code in the OK button which shows inside the reminder notification that pop up when time is due?

2) How to change the project name that display inside this reminder notification?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No, reminder look is not possible to change. All reminders must be freely recognizable be a user.

2) You can change it in WMAppManifest.xml (Title="") or in project settings: Application - Deployment options - Title.

Comment: Thanks. I am not changing the look or design of the Notification. I want to add some code insie the OK button to perform some tasks. So, can override the OKButton??

Comment: Add url to your reminder: `NavigationUri = new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?from_reminder=1", UriKind.Relative)`. Than check in `OnNavigatedTo` if app launched from reminder or not: `(e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.New && e.Uri.OriginalString.EndsWith("from_reminder=1")) { //Reminder code }`

Comment: thanks.Understand this step. very helpful. But I want to do something when I click the Okbutton when this notification pop up. I understand by clicking the Title of reminder with Uri will send to the page.

Comment: Where are you see OKButton? On reminder you have Snooze button that shifts reminder to few minutes, Dismiss button that closes the reminder and the Message area above buttons that launches your app. If you want to do something when user clicks on a Message area but don't launch your app, you could try some dirty hack: add very light page (probably even in different assembly) and pass Url to reminder to this page. On this page call something and throw an Exception that closes your app. Probably, your user won't see that what's happening but your code is called.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. you are right. I am talking about this snooze btn. So, I want to know, it is poosibe to override this snooze button so that user dont cick the messsage area to be transfered to the page indicated by the URI. I want to do some task. The snooze task is to reschedule the reminder. Can I do something else ? thanks

Comment: Thanks. I m you are right. Hope next time they can enhence this feature.

Comment: you could try some dirty hack: add very light page (probably even in different assembly) and pass Url to reminder to this page. On this page call something and throw an Exception that closes your app.

Comment: There is an example project that changed tile when reminder is fired (you must manually pin to start the app):  http://www.fileserve.com/file/7qFbxGm/reminder.zip